# Using the same class name in two namespaces - Prioritize one of them

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, namespaces

There are 2 classes with the same name in different namespaces.

One of them is a .aspx page and one is a business class which represents an entry in my database (I am using CSLA).

I'm working in the namespace of the aspx page and normally I'll never have a need to call the page class but often need to call the business class.

I've already been searching for a solution. What I found was to write a using part for a higher priority as others inside the namespace block of my page class. Problem here is that the namespace I'm writing in has still the highest priority and the page class is this namespace.

Is there a way to prioritize another namespace higher then the one I am currently writing in?

Comment: Your comment about the `using` keyword is spot on. Alias one of the classes out of the way. Fully qualify references to the other one, but only if you still need to.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to prioritize another namespace higher then the one I am currently writing in?

Not directly.  And I wouldn't want the compiler to "choose" a namespace if there was a collision, I'd want it to make me fix the collision, which is what it does.

I would either explicitly state the other namespace to avoid the collision or use an alias.

I see this a lot when mapping from ViewModels to Domain objects:

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class User
    {
    }
}

namespace ViewModel
{
    public class User
    {
        // another class with different properties
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using Domain;
using ViewModel;

public class UserController
{
    public Save(Model.User user)   
    {
        Domain.User dUser = Mapper.Map(user);
        repository.Save(dUser);
    }
}
```

or

```
using DUser = Domain.User;
using VMUser = ViewModel.User;

public class UserController
{
    public Save(VMUser user)   
    {
        DUser dUser = Mapper.Map(user);
        repository.Save(dUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: Already tried this. In case the compiler wouldn't take the right class it would cause an compiler error because no public property of my business class in also in my page class. So we always know wether it uses the right class or not...

Comment: +1 Very nice dump of an MVC example!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use this :

```
using newClassName = System.Text;
```

Comment: I was already trying to use an Alias for the current Namespace to exclude it from my scope. Result was that it's still in my scope and in the alias namespace either...